# using jQuery function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[codepen](http://codepen.io/bob_js/pen/mOmELy) this is the working code

I have a working code for changing the status of the network.
But I used jQuery to achieve it and now I am using angular app for the same thing.

Could you please help me.

Below is the Angular Code I have tried from already existing plunker:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3LkiI7Cj4RWBNRLEJUA?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Hello {{name}}! {{online}}
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
      $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = false;
        });
      }, false);
      $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.online = true;
        });
      }, false);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is.  Are you just trying to set a class if $scope.online is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/C2oJAYtEbb2lMixY2rVa?p=preview

```
  <div id="connection" ng-class="{'connected': online, 'disconnected': !online}">
    <span ng-if="$root.online">Online<div></div></span>
    <span ng-if="!$root.online">Offline<div></div></span>
  </div>
```

Note that with this approach, the initial state of 'connecting...' is not handled.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-class` like this:

```
<div id="connection"  ng-class="{'connected': online == true}">Online<div></div></div>
```

Here is your corrected [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/53qCqNOp6w1oe4Biu7Hf?p=preview)

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: yes this is very close, but how about offline. It won't change to offline like mine does. Could you please help Thank you